# wxWidgets 2.9.4 + Xcode 4.5.2 - Can't make it work

Tags: wxwidgets, xcode4.5, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having troubles trying to use wxWidgets 2.9.4 and Xcode 4.5.2, I get all sort of errors in the way.
First of all, I think I installed wxWidgets correctly, because every sample and demo run just fine. The problem is when I try to create an Xcode project.

1. When I follow the wxWidgets tutorial changing the build settings as follows:

   - Paste the --cppflags in "Other C++ Flags"
   - Paste the --libs in "Other Linker Flags" (REMOVING THE -L)
   - Change the compiler to GCC
     I get:
   - > ld: library not found for -lwxregexu-2.9
     >
     > clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
2. When I follow the http://zebratale.tumblr.com tutorial (seems more detailed to me)
   I get:

   > ld: library not found for -lwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-2.9
   >
   > clang: error: linker command failed with exit cod 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm completely lost and I'd appreciate any help

------------UPDATE------------------------

I just found out that it's possible to compile it using the terminal command:

> g++ -o main main.cpp './../../build-cocoa-debug/wx-config --debug --cxxflags --libs'

So I guess the problem is the compiler Xcode is using. But when I change it to LLMV GCC 4.2, I get the same error (YES, as if it was still using clang)
To change the compiler I went to build settings->build options->compiler for c/c++/objective-c  and changed it.

---------UPDATE2-----------------

Even now that I changed the compiler on Xcode the error is:

> ld: library not found for -lwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-2.9
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: can you just compile the steps to make it compile. That would help me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `--cxxflags` (C++ compiler flags), not `--cppflags` (C preprocessor flags).

Second, why do you remove `-L`? Of course the linker can't find the libraries if you remove the option telling it where they are.

Comment: Dear VZ,
I used > --cxxflags , not > -cppflags - it was just a typo. But thank you anyway! The second tip totally solved my problem. I was removing the -L because of the zebratale.tumblr.com tutorial, I swear I tried without removing it first and it didn't work, but... Now it did, so, thank you!